# How to invoke a python script after successfully running a Django view

Tags: python, django, django-views

Lets say I have a view page(request) which loads page.html.

Now after successfully loading page.html, I want to automatically run a python script behind the scene 10 - 15 sec after the page.html loaded. How it is possible?

Also, is it possible to show the status of the script dynamically (running/ stopped/ Syntax Error..etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runing a script from the javascript is not a clean way to do it, because the user can close the browser, disable js ... etc. instead you can use django-celery, it let you run backgroud scripts and you can check to status of the script dynamically from a middleware. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **client-side timeout** to AJAX back to the server 10-15 sec later. Point it to a different view and execute your script within that view. For example:

```
function runServerScript() {
    $.get("/yourviewurlhere", function(data) {
        // Do something with the return data
    });
}
setTimeout("runServerScript()", 10000);
```

If you want status to be displayed, the client would have to make multiple requests back to the server.

Comment: actually I have no knowledge on JS/ AJAX (thats the problem). so.. is there any small tutorial kind thing for this job??

Comment: @Surya: Your Google search is as good as mine... there are heaps of javascript / jQuery intros.

Comment: anyway.. its there any total pythonic way to do it .. for time being.

Comment: @Surya: No neat way that I'm aware of. Your Django view has to **return** data in order to send a response to your client - so you can't do any further processing after the response is sent. I guess you could spawn a new thread to do your processing 10 sec later, but that seems a little hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Celery](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGEQFjAC&url=http://celeryproject.org/&ei=Ai8JUNeCJcO6hAfSlOD6CQ&usg=AFQjCNGv_8j-HYF4vzl_wRkBXSmigZ3c2Q&sig2=FAK1mZT3wMF1yVaV_jGqvg) might come in handy for such use cases. You can start a task (or script as you call them) from a view (even with a delay, as you want). Sending status reports back to the browser will be harder unless you opt for something like WebSockets but that's highly experimental right now.